# Как поставить символ "→" в PyCharm вместо "->"?

Tags: python, pycharm

Как поставить символ "→" в PyCharm вместо "->"? Если прибегать к таблице символов - это неудобно, и IDE ругается на BAD_CHARACTER. Много раз в видео видел достаточно длинную стрелочку, которую ставят моментально.

Comment: В аннотации функций, что ли? `def foo() -> int:`? Это через шрифты. Находите шрифт, который такое делает с этими символами и используете в редакторе PyCharm

Comment: Да, в аннотации. Понял про шрифт, спасибо!

Comment: Вот этот использую и он хорош https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#ligatures

Comment: @gil9red если JetBrains не врёт, такой шрифт уже и так используется по умолчанию, только нужно в настройках лигатуры включить

Comment: Спасибо всем, помогли. Включил уже встроенный шрифт jetbrains mono и лигатуры к нему - заработало.